# How do I get my Django manage.py working properly when the files are accessed through a symlink?

Tags: python, django, linux, symlink

**Problem**

When trying to run one of my custom Django management commands (`send_notify_emails`), I get the following error:

```
$ python web_apps/manage.py send_notify_emails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_apps/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in setup_environ
    project_module = import_module(project_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named my_django_app-1.0
```

**Background**

I have a Django site with two apps in it. The path to the site directory (which includes the app module directories, as well as settings.py, urls.py and manage.py) is `/srv/web_apps`. This is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/my_django_app-1.0`, which is an `svn export` of a production release tag. This way I can change my app version over by just moving the symbolic link to the path for the new production version, and easily change back to an earlier release if I need to.

My `django.wsgi` file adds `/srv` and `/srv/web_apps` to the Python path so that `mod_wsgi` can find my settings and url files, as well as the app modules.

The ONLY place that `my_django_app-1.0` appears is the directory path, it is not anywhere in my `settings.py` or otherwise, so Django must be getting the module name from the path.

What *seems* to be happening is Django is resolving the package name for my app by following the symbolic link and using the name of the target folder, instead of the symbolic link itself. When I run `manage.py`, Django tries to import `my_django_app-1.0` when it should be importing `web_apps`.

Comment: In `django/core/management/__init__.py` between lines 394 and 401 is the code that is causing this action.  Specifically this:  `os.path.dirname(settings_mod.__file__)`.

Comment: @Jack I agree. Unfortunately I don't see how to set Django or my system up so I can serve my app through a symbolic link in such a way that `os.path.dirname(settings_mod.__file__)` resolves the right path for me. The Django code was written assuming Python modules are like file paths..

Comment: True.  I was simply trying to give more information for anyone attempting to answer, since I don't have one.  Have you considered using your version control to make this work?  Mercurial would probably do a better job of keeping your app up to date than this symlink / directory naming would.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a Django site with two apps in it. The path to the site
>   directory (which includes the app module directories, as well as
>   settings.py, urls.py and manage.py) is /srv/web_apps. This is a
>   symbolic link to /usr/share/my_django_app-1.0, which is an svn export
>   of a production release tag. This way I can change my app version over
>   by just moving the symbolic link to the path for the new production
>   version, and easily change back to an earlier release if I need to.

What you're describing is basically the exact reason why people like virtualenv so much.
I'd suggest taking a read through of [mod_wsgi Virtual Environments](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments).

The issue is that `__file__` is returning the symlink a relative path which depending
on where it's being imported from (inside a symlink'd path..), thats how it'll report
it's home. Since directories are the basic structure of modules, if you have a directory
with `__init__.py` in it, then whatever that directory is named will be the '**name**'
if you import it.

You might be able to override this behavior, but that'd be the wrong way to go about
things - check out virtualenv, or setup separate directories per version and just use
underscores instead of periods. **myApp_1_0_0**, etc.

Consider the following scenario

```
mkdir real_directory
ln -s real_directory symlink_directory
cat >>real_directory/__init__.py <<EOF
import os
print
print '__name__ == %s' % (__name__)
print '__file__ == %s' % (__file__)
print ' abspath == %s' % os.path.abspath(__file__)
print 'realpath == %s' % os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print
EOF
```

**python -c "import real_directory"**

```
__name__ == real_directory
__file__ == real_directory/__init__.py
 abspath == /Users/nar/pt/real_directory/__init__.py
realpath == /Users/nar/pt/real_directory/__init__.py
```

**python -c "import symlink_directory"**

```
__name__ == symlink_directory
__file__ == symlink_directory/__init__.pyc
 abspath == /Users/nar/pt/symlink_directory/__init__.pyc
realpath == /Users/nar/pt/real_directory/__init__.pyc
```